# Calling variables from concatenated strings

Tags: r, concatenation

I have three variables which I want to call from a vector containing variable names produced by concatenating the string "variable." with the suffix "ONE", "TWO" and "THREE", as per code below:

```
variable.ONE <- 1
variable.TWO <- 2
variable.THREE <- 3
j <- c("ONE","TWO","THREE")
variables <- paste0("variable.",j)
```

"Variables" prints:

```
variables
[1] "variable.ONE"   "variable.TWO"   "variable.THREE"
```

I am looking for a way to return the values of all three variables contained in the vector "variables", hence:

```
[1] 1 2 3
```

However, calling the variables contained in "variables" does not work as intended:

`get(variables)` produces:

```
[1] 1
```

`eval(noquote(variables)))` produces:

```
[1] variable.ONE   variable.TWO   variable.THREE
```

`eval(as.name(variables)))` produces:

```
[1] 1
```

These attempts are only three of many, none of which brought me to the desired - and simple - output of:

```
[1] 1 2 3
```

Therefore, I would greatly appreciate any help you may be able to offer!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mget(variables)` for a character vector, returning a list of objects.

Note that there is no way to ensure that each element of `variables` refers to an atomic object of the same type (e.g., what if `variable.TWO <- "b"`?), so it is expected that the result should be a list instead of a vector.

You can achieve your desired output with `unlist(mget(variables))`.